# Is There a Query for Indexes?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I want know what are the indexes of a table. I am using ASE ISQL and I can know the indexes by right click on the table and selecting DDL, however, there is a developer in another machine that his not familiar to sybase, and I want to know the indexes of his database (his using ASE).

Is there a query for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to view the indexes in your database.

`sp_helpindex` can be used to show the indexes associated with a particular table.

```
sp_helpindex TABLE_NAME
```

`sp_help` can be used to list all the properties of a table, including the associated indexes.

```
sp_help TABLE_NAME
```

To get the list of all indexes and their associated tables you can use the following query

```
use DATABASE_NAME
go

select sysobjects.name as TABLE_NAME, sysindexes.name as INDEX_NAME
from sysobjects,sysindexes where
sysobjects.type = 'U' and
sysobjects.id = sysindexes.id and
sysindexes.indid between 1 and 254
order by sysobjects.name,sysindexes.indid
go
```

Comment: thanx you alot i cannot vote you because of my low rep but your defently helping me

Answer (score 2):

This code will generate the code indexes:

```
use [database]
go
declare @objectName sysname
declare @username sysname
declare @fullname sysname
declare @id int

select
  @id = o.id,
  @objectName = o.name,
  @username = u.name,
  @fullname =  u.name + '.' + o.name
from
  dbo.sysobjects o,
  dbo.sysusers u
where
  o.name = 'Table'
  and o.Type in ( 'U', 'S' )
  and u.uid = o.uid
  and u.name = 'Owner'

select
  [index] = 1000 * i.indid,
  text =
    'create' +
    case i.status & 2
      when 2 then ' unique '
      else ' '
    end +
    case ( i.status & 16 ) + ( i.status2 & 512 )
      when 0 then
        'nonclustered'
      else
        'clustered'
    end +
    ' index [' + i.name + '] on ' + @fullname + ' ('
from
  dbo.sysindexes i
where
  i.indid > 0
  and i.indid < 255
  and i.id = @id
  and i.status2 & 2 != 2

union all

select
  [index] = 1000 * i.indid + c.colid,
  text =
    ' ' + index_col ( @fullname, i.indid, c.colid ) +
  case
    when c.colid < i.keycnt - case when i.indid = 1 then 0 else 1 end then
      ', '
  end
from
  dbo.sysindexes i,
  dbo.syscolumns c
where
  i.indid > 0
  and i.indid < 255
  and i.id = @id
  and i.status2 & 2 != 2

  and c.id = @id
  and c.colid <= i.keycnt - case when i.indid = 1 then 0 else 1 end

union all

select
  [index] = 1000 * i.indid + 999,
  text =
    ' )' || char ( 13 ) || char ( 10 ) || 'go' || char ( 13 ) || char ( 10 )
from
  dbo.sysindexes i
where
  i.indid > 0
  and i.indid < 255
  and i.id = @id
  and i.status2 & 2 != 2

order by
  [index]
go
```